# App Service equivalent of a Static Web App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

Is there an out of the box way to create a static web site as an Azure App Service WebApp instead of as an Azure Static WebApp.

I know I can create an ASP Core web app and just ignore the Razor pages, but I'm wondering whether there is a cleaner approach.

Background:

I have an API for which I wish to provide a web interface. My API already exists as a Function App. If I use an Azure Static Web App, then because I want to access a 'bring your own' Function App instead of a managed Function App supplied with the Static Web App, this means I would have to use a Standard hosting plan. This costs $10/month which is excessive for my requirements. If I can host a static website on a free tier App Service plan it would cost me nothing.

My Function App needs to be a standalone one as it uses features not available to the managed Function App you get with a Static Web App on the Free hosting plan. I also want to keep my architecture decoupled.

Although I don't need my website to have a dedicated backend, it would still be nice to be able to have the kind of out of the box support for authentication and storage access that you get with a Static Web App or an App Service Web App.

I'm thinking I could just create a free plan Static Web App and then use the managed Function App backend to relay requests to my existing Function App, but I'm wondering whether there is a better way to achieve my goal.

Comment: I'm thinking I could just create a free plan Static Web App and then use the managed Function App backend to relay requests to my existing Function App > this would be an Ideal way, But an alternative is to spin up a Free Vm with B1s size that comes free and run your app there.

Comment: Also, Creating a static website as an Azure App Service WebApp is possible. Your static website can be deployed to an existing WebApp. You can store your static website files in Azure Blob Storage and subsequently deploy them to your WebApp. A backend for your static website can also be provided using Azure Functions. An existing Azure Functions app can be connected to an Azure Static Web Apps resource.

Comment: Azure Functions can also be used to add an API to Azure Static Web Apps.By integrating with Azure services, Azure Static Web Apps offer built-in serverless API endpoints. The provision of integrated security includes direct access to user authentication and role-based authorization data.

Comment: Refer these 2 documents - 1) https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own.md 2) https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/apis-overview.md

Comment: You don't even need an app service to host a website. you can serve it right out of an azure storage account.  within the storage account, you can enable "static web site" and you provide an index.html and 404.html page, and it creates a $web container which it serves web content from.  You can also set up a custom domain name. This way, you can keep your existing functions app as-is.

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy your static web app contents in Azure Web app service instead of using Azure Static Web app and store your source code in Blob storage and utilize Azure Web app Free Tier.

[image]

After deploying your Web app, you can import your Function app with Azure APIM instance and then connect the APIM instance function API with your Web app like below:-

[**Reference1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api)

[image]

One more alternative is to deploy an Azure VM with B1s size that is a Free Size, And deploy your application inside it.

> I'm thinking I could just create a free plan Static Web App and then use the managed Function App backend to relay requests to my existing Function App

Yes,  if you want to utilize Bring your own Function in Azure static web app unfortunately you are required to upgrade your static web app tier to Standard plan from Free plan. If you want this feature to be available for Free plan in Azure static web app you can raise a github feature request [here.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new?title=&body=%0A%0A%5BEnter%20feedback%20here%5D%0A%0A%0A---%0A####%20Document%20Details%0A%0A%E2%9A%A0%20*Do%20not%20edit%20this%20section.%20It%20is%20required%20for%20learn.microsoft.com%20%E2%9E%9F%20GitHub%20issue%20linking.*%0A%0A*%20ID:%202af70bd0-a356-b007-1087-7f6fc0ebf844%0A*%20Version%20Independent%20ID:%2013153062-fc32-4907-2d5d-a37ed5ada5cf%0A*%20Content:%20%5BBring%20your%20own%20functions%20to%20Azure%20Static%20Web%20Apps%5D%28https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own%29%0A*%20Content%20Source:%20%5Barticles/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own.md%5D%28https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own.md%29%0A*%20Service:%20**static-web-apps**%0A*%20GitHub%20Login:%20@craigshoemaker%0A*%20Microsoft%20Alias:%20**cshoe**)

[image]

**Reference:-**

[API support for Azure static web app.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/apis-overview.md)

[Bring your own Function in Azure static web app](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own.md)